# Facing error while using faster_rcnn_resnet101_v1_640x640_coco17_tpu-8 of model_zoo in Tensorflow==2.5

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-model-garden

I am using `python 3.8` and `tensor flow=2.5` and I want to use `faster_rcnn_resnet101_v1_640x640_coco17_tpu-8` model to do the object detection but I am facing following error.

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py", line 113, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\priyabrata\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Users\priyabrata\anaconda3\envs\new_tfod_env\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\priyabrata\anaconda3\envs\new_tfod_env\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py", line 104, in main
    model_lib_v2.train_loop(
  File "C:\Users\priyabrata\anaconda3\envs\new_tfod_env\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.8.egg\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 535, in train_loop
    detection_model = MODEL_BUILD_UTIL_MAP['detection_model_fn_base'](
  File "C:\Users\priyabrata\anaconda3\envs\new_tfod_env\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.8.egg\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 1199, in build
    return build_func(getattr(model_config, meta_architecture), is_training,
  File "C:\Users\priyabrata\anaconda3\envs\new_tfod_env\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.8.egg\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 391, in _build_ssd_model
    _check_feature_extractor_exists(ssd_config.feature_extractor.type)
  File "C:\Users\priyabrata\anaconda3\envs\new_tfod_env\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.8.egg\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 263, in _check_feature_extractor_exists
    raise ValueError('{} is not supported. See `model_builder.py` for features '
ValueError:  is not supported. See `model_builder.py` for features extractors compatible with different versions of Tensorflow
```

Comment: Hi @Priyabrata Panda, this error happens when you are using Tensorflow 1.x object detection models and running them with Tensorflow 2.x .To use Tensorflow 1.x models, run with tensorflow version 1.15.0, it should work.These models will not work with tensorflow 2.x. Thank you!